# Mongodb connection to table in function

Tags: mongodb, function

I don't know how should refer I to a table, maybe someone knows and can help:

Collection:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a5e40636494620e7471c51b"), 
"uczelnia" : "Politechnika Wroclawska", 
"ulica" : "Jodlowa 15", 
"doktorzy" : [
    {
        "imie" : "Mateusz", 
        "nazwisko" : "Laskowski"
    }, 
    {
        "imie" : "Piotr", 
        "nazwisko" : "Potrzebny"
    }
], 
"miejscowosc" : "Wroclaw"
}ObjectId("5a5e40636494620e7471c51b"
```

Function:

```
function dane_o_uczelni(id) {
uczelnia1= db.uczelnia.findOne({"_id" : id})
if(uczelnia1!==null)
{
print("Uczelnia: "+     uczelnia1.uczelnia)
print("Miejscowosc: " + uczelnia1.miejscowosc)
print("Doktorzy: " +    uczelnia1.doktorzy.nazwisko)
}
else return null
}
dane_o_uczelni(ObjectId("5a5e40636494620e7471c51b"));
```

I want to see on output all of my Doctor(doktorzy) in ObjectId("5a5e40636494620e7471c51b" with  surname (nazwisko). With this code I see only `uczelnia` and `ulica`, in `nazwisko` I see information undefined..

Comment: `uczelnia1.doctorzy` is an array and has no key `nazwisko`... Btw, is this Javascript? Because `findOne` returns a promise, hence your code above should not work (as `uczelnia1` is a promise, not an object with fields `uczelnia`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for answer, it can help me :) Mongodb use javascript and json code :)